# custom ng-if directive angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to create a directive that works like the **ng-if** directive, so I would like to grab it's functionality. I created a directive like this:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('sapphire.directives').directive('ifScreensize', directive);

    function directive(ngIfDirective, $window) {
        var ngIf = ngIfDirective[0];

        return {
            controller: 'IfScreensizeController',
            prority: 1,
            scope: {
                options: '=ifScreensize'
            },
            link: function (scope, element, attrs, controller) {
                scope.$watch('options', function (options) {
                    controller.handle(element, options, ngIf);
                });

                var window = angular.element($window)
                window.bind('resize', function () {
                    $timeout(function () {
                        controller.handle(element, scope.options, ngIf);
                    }, 500);
                });
            }
        };
    };
})();
```

And then the controller looks like this:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('sapphire.directives').controller('IfScreensizeController', controller);

    function controller(ifScreensizeService) {
        this.handle = ifScreensizeService.handle;
    };
})();
```

And finally, the service looks like this:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('sapphire.directives').service('ifScreensizeService', service);

    function service($window) {
        return {
            handle: handle
        };

        //////////////////////////////////////////////////

        function handle(element, options, ngIf) {
            var window = angular.element($window),
                width = $window.innerWidth,
                value = true;

            switch (options.operator) {
                case '>':
                    value = options.width >= width;
                    break;
                case '>=':
                    value = options.width > width;
                    break;
                case '<':
                    value = options.width < width;
                    break;
                case '<=':
                    value = options.width <= width;
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }

            ngIf.link.apply(ngIf, value);
        };
    };
})();
```

The problem is, when I try to use the directive I get an error:

> TypeError: CreateListFromArrayLike called on non-object

Which is on the `ngIf.link.apply(ngIf, value);` line. 
Can someone tell me what i need to do to get the directive to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I used the actual [ng-if directive](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngIf.js) code to create my directive.
So, I changed the directive to this:

```
angular.module('sapphire.directives').directive('ifScreensize', directive);

function directive($timeout, $window) {
    return {
        controller: 'IfScreensizeController',
        multiElement: true,
        transclude: 'element',
        priority: 600,
        terminal: true,
        restrict: 'A',
        $$tlb: true,
        bindToController: {
            options: '=ifScreensize'
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, controller, transclude) {
            scope.$watch('options', function (options) {
                controller.handle(element, attrs, transclude);
            });

            var window = angular.element($window)
            window.bind('resize', function () {
                $timeout(function () {
                    controller.handle(element, attrs, transclude);
                }, 500);
            });
        }
    };
};
```

And I changed the controller to mimic the **ng-if** directive like this:

```
angular.module('sapphire.directives').controller('IfScreensizeController', controller);

function controller($animate, $compile, ifScreensizeService) {
    var self = this;        
    var block, childScope, previousElements;

    self.handle = function handle($element, $attr, $transclude) {
        var value = ifScreensizeService.evaulate(self.options);

        console.log(value);

        if (value) {
            if (!childScope) {
            $transclude(function(clone, newScope) {
                childScope = newScope;
                clone[clone.length++] = $compile.$$createComment('end ngIf', $attr.ngIf);
                // Note: We only need the first/last node of the cloned nodes.
                // However, we need to keep the reference to the jqlite wrapper as it might be changed later
                // by a directive with templateUrl when its template arrives.
                block = {
                clone: clone
                };
                $animate.enter(clone, $element.parent(), $element);
            });
            }
        } else {
            if (previousElements) {
                console.log(previousElements);
                previousElements.remove();
                previousElements = null;
            }
            if (childScope) {
                childScope.$destroy();
                childScope = null;
            }
            if (block) {
                previousElements = ifScreensizeService.getBlockNodes(block.clone);
                $animate.leave(previousElements).done(function(response) {
                    if (response !== false) previousElements = null;
                });
                block = null;
            }
        }
    };
};
```

The bulk of the code there, is found in the **ng-if** directive. I just modified it slightly to work with my directive.
One thing to notice is that in the original **ng-if** directive, it invokes `getBlockNodes` which we do not have access to, so I added this to my service:

```
angular.module('sapphire.directives').service('ifScreensizeService', service);

function service($window) {
    var slice = [].slice;
    return {
        evaulate: evaulate,
        getBlockNodes: getBlockNodes
    };

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////

    function evaulate(options) {
        var window = angular.element($window),
            width = $window.innerWidth,
            value = true;

        switch (options.operator) {
            case '>':
                value = width >= options.width;
                break;
            case '>=':
                value = width > options.width;
                break;
            case '<':
                value = width < options.width;
                break;
            case '<=':
                value = width <= options.width;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        console.log(options, width, value);

        return value;
    };

    function getBlockNodes(nodes) {
        // TODO(perf): update `nodes` instead of creating a new object?
        var node = nodes[0];
        var endNode = nodes[nodes.length - 1];
        var blockNodes;

        for (var i = 1; node !== endNode && (node = node.nextSibling); i++) {
            if (blockNodes || nodes[i] !== node) {
                if (!blockNodes) {
                    console.log(nodes);
                    blockNodes = angular.element(slice.call(nodes, 0, i));
                }
                blockNodes.push(node);
            }
        }

        return blockNodes || nodes;
    };
};
```

And the last caveat here was this line:

```
blockNodes = angular.element(slice.call(nodes, 0, i));
```

In the original **ng-if**, it is actually:

```
blockNodes = jqLite(slice.call(nodes, 0, i));
```

I struggled to get this to work, but basically the method **jqLite** is actually doing an `angular.element()` call. The **slice** method won't work unless you do `var slice = [].slice;` which I have done at the top of the service.

I hope this helps someone else :)

Answer (score 0):

`.apply` takes an array. Try calling it this way `ngIf.link.apply(ngIf, [value]);`

Comment: yeah, I tried that and I got this error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'ngIf' of undefined` which I could see what part of the **ng-if** directive looking for the value parameter. I tried to pass the attributes into my method and set it like this: `attrs.$set('ngIf', value);` and `attrs.$set('ng-if', value);`. Both returned the same error

Comment: i'm guessing it from `ngIfDirective`.